# FeathersJS socketio client disconnect?

Tags: socket.io, feathersjs

I'm developing an Electron app that connects to a FeathersJS server using FeathersJS SocketIO client. It works properly using the code provided at FeathersJS documentation, but I'd like the possibility to connect/disconnect the client from the server, basically to connect to another server (with exactly the same services). The example would be: I have 2 FeathersJS servers with exactly the same services but with different data stored, and I want my Electron app to be able to connect to server number 1, then disconnect and connect to server number 2.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is probably to initialized two Feathers applications that you can swap out accordingly in your Electron app. A slightly more hacky way would be to replace the connection on the application (`app.io`) and the [initialized client services](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/application.html#services) (`service.connection`):

```
const replaceConnection = (app, socket) => {
  app.io = socket;

  Object.keys(app.services).forEach(name => {
    app.service(name).connection = socket;
  });

  return app;
}
```

Comment: Hello Daff. I didn't explain my problem with enough detail. I don't want to be connected to 2 servers at the same time, but to change the server according to user's input. So my Electron app will start, read the server address from a config file and try to connect to that server. If the user changes the server address (not previously known) through the app UI, then the Electron app should close the connection to the first server and then connect to the new one. I cannot see a "good" way of doing this in Javascript because of the way "require" works. Maybe wrapping FeathersJS client into class?

Comment: Why would that need `require`? I think all you'd have to do is a `createApp(url)` function that returns a Feathers application for a URL and the ability to swap out the returned `app` object throughout your application.

Comment: Hello Daff, I've tried your suggestion of a simple function that returns a new feathersClient and it works... I'm not very used on how NodeJs and Javascript work, so I think I'm overcomplicating my code... Thank you for your help!